# Matplotlib: Iteratively draw/erase one plot over a background plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to accomplish something hopefully pretty basic. Hoping for a few pointers!

I want to draw two circles: one that stays on the screen, and one that iteratively grows larger. For the one that changes, I essentially want to use a loop to draw and erase, so that it will draw a larger circle on each iteration (accomplishing an effect where it appears that a second, animated circle is growing). Below is what I've managed to work out so far. It's drawing the second circle progressively larger with each loop, but not erasing.

```
import matplotlib as plt
plt.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Initialize a variable
CHANGE = 0.3

#Make static 1st circle
circle1 = plt.Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.2, color='white')
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
plt.axis('off')
ax.add_artist(circle1)
fig.set_facecolor("black")

#Animate dynamic 2nd circle
def frange(start, stop, step): 
     i = start
     while i < stop:
         yield i
         i += step

for step in frange(0, .6, .01):     
    circle2 = plt.Circle((0.5, 0.5), CHANGE, color='gray', fill=False)  
    ax.add_artist(circle2)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(.001) 
    #plt.cla( )    
    CHANGE = CHANGE + step
```

*Note: I played around with adding plt.cla() into the loop. While I was able to get it to erase/redraw circle 2 by doing that, it seems to draw over the original circle 1, versus keeping both visible in the same plot.*

~~~~~~~~~~~~~

A) What it should like on each loop:

[image]

B) What it's looking like when not erasing:

[image]

(Using Python3.6.5 via PycharmCE)

Comment: You can remove an artist via `artist.remove()`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : you rock! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting the dots, based on ImportanceOfBeingEarnest's comment, for any newbies out there like me:

Added the following **starred** line of code into the loop:

```
for step in frange(0, .6, .01):  
    circle2 = plt.Circle((0.5, 0.5), CHANGE, color='gray', fill=False)  
    ax.add_artist(circle2)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(.001)            
    **circle2.remove()**
    CHANGE = CHANGE + step
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of multiple calls to `add_artist` and `remove()`, you should simply call the the `Circle` class's [`set_radius` method](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Circle.html#matplotlib.patches.Circle.set_radius). This will be more performant.